# How can I modify this class to check if a list of lists is empty or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am trying to build a class object that can take in a list of lists and check the entries to see if one is empty, and if it does, returns a message.

```py
class EmptyCheck():
    def __init__(self, some_list):
        self.some_list = some_list
    
    def check_empty(some_list):
        for item in some_list:
            if '' in item:
                print('please fill out survey')


data = [[1],[2],[''],['apples']]
x = EmptyCheck(data)
x.check_empty()
```

The problem seems to be that the `EmptyCheck` object is not iterable. But this is where I get a bit confused because I am not trying to iterate over the `EmptyCheck` object, I am trying to iterate over `some_list`. So I am hoping someone could help to clarify what is going on and help me to understand this issue a bit deeper. I suspect I will need to add some of the special dunder methods, but maybe I don't?

Comment: You forgot `self` as the first argument to `check_empty()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `check_empty` method checks a new list passed as a function argument, not the list you store as an instance attribute. Change it to:

```
def check_empty(self):
    for item in self.some_list:
```

As a side note, you should `return` right after the `print` statement so that you don't print the same message multiple times in case there are multiple sub-lists with empty strings.

Comment: Yeah ... I totally forgot about the `self` argument inside of the method